# Free Windows VM to clone existing physical drive

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualization, virtual-machines

I'm looking for a freeware virtual machine program that will run under Windows 7 x64, which will allow me to clone an existing physical Windows XP x32 drive to a virtual disk.

Answer (score 1):

The sysinternals application [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) will hot copy an online windows instance using VSS and output a valid Windows virtual machine. From there you can import the VHD into Virtualbox and run what was your physical machine as a virtual machine.